# Electron BrowserView Renderer process vs WebView

Tags: webview, electron, chromium

I am porting an Electron app from a traditional renderer + webview architecture to one that uses `BrowserView` objects. The application uses some `BrowserWindows` to display a `webview` fullscreen in all available monitors. The renderer processes hold basically an `index.html` with a `webview` at 100% size.

I am little confused about the renderer process and the BrowserViews.

With the new approach, I just inject the `preload` script into the `BrowserView` constructor, and do not load any page on the `BrowserWindow` themselves:

```
browserViewOptions = {
    webPreferences: {
        preload: (__dirname + "/preload.js"),
        partition: "persist:ns",
        nodeIntegration: false,
        plugins: false
    }
};
```

1. What renderer process is this? Is it the traditional render process where the `webviews` used to be? Or do the `BrowserViews` have their own renderer process?

   1. If it is the traditional way, is it shared in the case where I also load a page in the `BrowserWindow`?
2. Does it matter that **I am not loading a page into the `BrowserWindow`**? I mean, if I don't load a page in the `BrowserWindow` (and just create the window to attach a `BrowserView` to it), **is there another Chromium process with an empty page running**?

   1. If yes, can this be prevented if I am only interested in the `BrowserView`?
3. Are there "overdraw" issues if I keep stuff on the `BrowserWindow` and occasionally hide the `BrowserViews` to display them?

Answer (score 1):

> What renderer process is this?

Unlike the `<webview>`, the `BrowserView` does not use another renderer process. You can verify this by observing the number of processes that appear when running some basic code like this:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
const view = new BrowserView();
view.webContents.loadFile("index.html");
mainWindow.setBrowserView(view);
```

You won't get an extra renderer process.

> Does it matter that I am not loading a page into the BrowserWindow?

A difference in what exactly? The number of renderer processes? No, it doesn't.

> is there another Chromium process with an empty page running? If yes, can this be prevented if I am only interested in the BrowserView?

Are you asking if the empty `BrowserWindow` results in a redundant renderer process with "about:blank" in it? It doesn't result in an extra process, but yes I believe the window is implicitly navigated to about:blank. (I could be wrong about this though, because `mainWindow.webContents.getURL()` logs `""`. Explicitly navigating it to `"about:blank"` correctly logs `"about:blank"`).

You don't really need to prevent anything.

However, I will add that if your entire window is going to load a single `BrowserView` with node integration turned off, as far as I can tell, you don't get any benefit from using a `BrowserView` and should just do the following instead:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        preload: (__dirname + "/preload.js"),
        partition: "persist:ns",
        nodeIntegration: false,
        plugins: false
    }
});
```

> Are there "overdraw" issues if I keep stuff on the BrowserWindow and occasionally hide the BrowserViews to display them?

You may need to clarify what your question is, but the stuff loaded into the `BrowserWindow` will always be there and will appear when hiding the `BrowserView`.